# Why does function finish running before Twitter get call is completed? (Twit)

Tags: javascript, twitter, npm

So, I am using the Twit package to use the Twitter API, and there is one function that I have that is meant to check for duplicate tweets:

```
function checkDuplicate(tweet){
  var isDuplicate = false;
  var params = {
    screen_name: "reddevilsbot",
    count: 1
  }
  T.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function (err, data, response){
    for(var j = 0; j < 1; j++){

      console.log('data: ', data[j].text.substring(0, 10));
      console.log('tweet: ', tweet.substring(0,10));
      console.log(data[j].text.substring(0, 10) == tweet.substring(0,10));

      if(data[j].text.substring(0, 10) == tweet.substring(0,10)){
        console.log('Im here');
        isDuplicate = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  });
  return isDuplicate;
}
```

If you are not familiar the Twitter API, what I am doing here is calling my own twitter handle in the params variable, then I call a get for statuses under a specific user. I am then given a data object that would return exactly one tweet, in this scenario.

So, for the sake of testing, I am checking ONLY the most recent tweet (hence, why `count` is set to 1), and I am passing a tweet into `checkDuplicate()` that is identical to the one I am comparing to. I have five logs to the console. The first one is outside of the function, and it is logging the result of `checkDuplicate()`, the rest are shown above. The results of the console are shown below.

```
    false
    data:  "Antonio V
    tweet:  "Antonio V
    true
    Im here
```

Seeing this leaves me to conclude that the `checkDuplicate()` is returning `isDuplicate` before the `get` call is finished. Is this true? If so, how do I make sure that the `checkDuplicate()` is waiting for the `get` call to finish?

Thanks

Comment: because it is asynchronous. You call a pizza place, you hang up the phone, and you expect to eat your pizza.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! 

That's what I was thinking. Thank you, I have a solution for this problem now that I know that!

Comment: I was going to answer this but it got closed...  

Heres what I came up with: https://gist.github.com/shaun-sweet/6d190bb58b475e967ebe67db3958beeb

Comment: Thank you! The first comment, it looked like you were trying to give me a link to documentation. It didn't seem to go through. Could you comment it here so I could see it? Thanks